# New line breaks typescript code in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs

I have this code which works as expected;

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'media-tracker-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styles: ['      h1 {            color: #ffffff;     }']
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

but if I put some new lines in to make the CSS more readable like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'media-tracker-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styles: ['      h1 {            
        color: #ffffff;     
    }']
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

... then it breaks my code.

In the console I get:
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

I am just starting to learn Angular 2... any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's totally unrelated to either TypeScript or AngularJS: JavaScript strings using `'` and `"` are not multilines.

You have two options:

- Use a backslash to escape end of line

---

```
var a = 'hey\
you';
```

- Use ES6 template strings (using backticks):

---

```
var a = `hey
you`;
```

Comment: thanks guys, yes I was using the wrong syntax. I did not realise that it was a backtick and not a quote coming from PHP background.. Thanks

Comment: not always easy to remember the tiny differences between each languages. If that answer helped you, feel free to mark as resolved.

Comment: yeah thanks picking up all the little differences all the time! I tried to mark your answer as complete, but it would not count the point because my profile is not good enough yet! Thanks again

Comment: rather than the up arrow, I think you should see a green mark/check under it to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting text in ` (backticks) instead of single quotes '?

You can check this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html):

> ```
> template: `
>   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
>   <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
> ```
>
> The template is a multi-line string within ECMAScript 2015 backticks (`). The backtick (`) — which is not the same character as a single quote (') — has many nice features. The feature we're exploiting here is the ability to compose the string over several lines, which makes for much more readable HTML.